# How to create a django model record using get_or_create and select_related

Tags: django, django-models

I have a class like below:

```
class GroupProduct(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(
           'myapp.Products'
           related_name='myapp_group_product')


   @classmethod
   def create_group_product(cls, p_id, product_id):
       cls.objects.get_or_create(id=p_id, defaults=dict(product=product_id).select_related('product')
```

So I expect it creates a record in the table with the following params, however it doesn't.

```
GP = GroupProduct()
GP.create_group_product(3, 225)
```

It says it product must be a `myapp.Products` instance. Is there any way to use select_related in this way rather than doing a seprate query and hit the database?

Comment: `cls.objects.select_related('product').get_or_create(id=p_id, defaults={'product_id': product_id})`?

Comment: What do you need `select_related` in `get_or_create` for?

Comment: @Ersain: I think to fetch the `product` item when the item is fetched from the db directly in the same query.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I did not take into account that the fetched object can then be used, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with:

```
cls.objects.select_related('product').get_or_create(
    id=p_id,
    defaults={'product_id': product_id}
)
```

If the item already exists, it will fetch the `product` data with the same query. If it does not (yet) exists, it will make an insert query, and you can then fetch the `Product` in a second query, since it will not make any fetch query and thus simply create a record and return a `cls` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this should be the solution. Just geting an error that product_id does not exist in the Products table. tried to add `exists()` at the end but says tuple does not have exists(). Do you know how can I skip ids which does not exist?

Comment: @schedulingqs: if you use `product_id`, then that `product_id` needs to be the primary key of a valid `Product` object. Note that `get_or_create` returns a 2-tuple with the first item the object, and the second a boolean, so you use `...[0]` to get the object. Since it is an object however, it makes no sense to use `.exists()` since the `.get_or_create` is guaranteed to retrieve an item that is in the database, or raise an error.

Comment: Does it work the same with prefetch_related?